# jQuery hide() on empty selection does not trigger callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use jQuery to filter a table on a page. I would like to fade out the currently displayed rows and fade in the rows matching the new selection. My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('#details-table tr').hide();
var previousFilterResult = $();
var selects = $('#search-panel > select');
selects.change(function () {
    selects.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var filterResult = filterTable();

    previousFilterResult.hide('slow', function () {
        filterResult.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            selects.removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });

    previousFilterResult = filterResult;
});
```

My problem is that when I initialize previousFilterResult with $() the code does not work as it never seems to hit the callback for the previousFilterResult.hide call. If I put a dummy div in the page and initialize previousFilterResult with $('#dummyDiv') it works fine.

Is there any way I can initialize previousFilterResult without putting a dummy div on the page so that the above code still works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) :

> it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

But you can easily change your code to

```
$('#details-table tr').hide();
var previousFilterResult = null;
var selects = $('#search-panel > select');
selects.change(function () {
    selects.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var filterResult = filterTable();
    var callback = function () {
        filterResult.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            selects.removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    };
    if (previousFilterResult) previousFilterResult.hide('slow', callback);
    else callback();
    previousFilterResult = filterResult;
});
```

This is cleaner than using `$()` which feel like a hack in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. My code looked like this before but I thought I could get rid of the if/else by initializing the previousFilterResult 'somehow'.

Comment: In my opinion, the intent is clearer with this code. If you were concerned about performances you have to consider this `if` is very little compared to what happens in `hide` and around.

Comment: I changed the code back, I also made some changes using promise().done() so the callback is only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

Note this from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide):

> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete. ... **If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.**

*(My emphasis)*

So if you want to call the function *once*, you need to handle that another way. For instance:

```
selects.change(function () {
    var fired = false; // Remember whether we've fired the callback

    selects.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var filterResult = filterTable();

    // Do we have any previous result?    
    if (previousFilterResult && previousFilterResult[0]) {
        // Yes, and there's at least one element in the set,
        // hide it/them and schedule a callback
        previousFilterResult.hide('slow', done);
    }
    else {
        // No, go ahead and fire our callback directly
        done();
    }

    previousFilterResult = filterResult;

    function done() {
        // If there were multiple results, we might get multiple calls,
        // so keep track of whether we've been called (fired)
        if (!fired) {
            fired = true;
            filterResult.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                selects.removeAttr('disabled');
            });
        }
    }
});
```